# How to ask a user input and use it as a parameter for a stored procedure in a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Sorry for the newbie question, but I have this task which kind of got me stuck. 
So, I made a database in PhpMyAdmin, created a table with data : `Products(id, name, city)` and created a stored procedure that will actually do a query on the table to find out the product with a certain name (which will be input-ed by the user on the web page). My stored procedure is: `proc_test` and takes one VARCHAR paramter.

So, how can I do this in a php script? How can i ask the user for some data, (on the site he should have like a box to type it) then click a search button, and get redirected to the page with the query results. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "practice";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "CALL proc_test('pencil');";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['numec'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Here, of course, I manually give the parameter in the script. But I don't know how to change this and ask for a user input instead. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` to send the data from your website to the php file where you can search for it in the database and send that data back to the user. In my example, the data is being displayed on the same webpage. You could `echo` the link to the website  and redirect the user on the webpage using `JavaScript` if you really wanted to but my example is just a proof of concept.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input required type="text" id="user_input">
        <button onclick="sendData()">Search</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script>
            function sendData() {
                var var_params = $('#user_input').val();

                $.post('test.php', {params: var_params}, function(data) { 
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your search result: " + data;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['params'])) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "practice";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // Create connection

        if ($conn->connect_error) { // Check connection
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $param = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['params']);

        $sql = "CALL proc_test('$param');";
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['numec']. "<br/>";
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```